# Imprint of the cursor sticks at the center of my screen on 14.04 after unlocking the screen

Tags: cursor, mouse-pointer

After logging out and in (using <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd>) I see a pointer/cursor which is frozen in the middle of my screen. The real pointer works fine, but the frozen one is quite annoying. It disappears when I turn off the computer, but the next time I lock & unlock the screen it's back. I'm using Ubuntu 14.04.

Answer (score 1):

I solved the problem by going to
**System Settings -> Displays** and turning off **Unknown Display**.